# OpenLayers WFS GetFeature large amount of data

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I am using WFS GetFeature request to GeoServer from OpenLayers application. And highlight different color that return features on map. This is working fine for 990 records. But not returning for 1800 record.

I am using AJAX request:

```
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cits/wms?"
            + "REQUEST=GetFeature&"
            + "SERVICE=WFS&"
            + "version=1.1.0&" 
            + "typename=pipes&" 
            + "outputFormat=text/javascript&"
            + "format_options=&" 
            + "callback: JSON_CALLBACK";
```

No error and no record. I thing it is timed out. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: you can help us by providing more information, what url is sent to the server, what does the response look like in the debugger, is there a log file entry on the server, what does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Basic rule for OpenLayers and WFS is that do not test with OpenLayers. With a browser you can control what happens. Some first steps to take:

- How many features there are in the service?
  http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&resulttype=hits&
- Can you get all data out in default format (GML)?
  http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&
- Can you get all data out also in GeoJSON?
  http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&outputformat=application/json&
- If you can't get out all the features, how many features you can get (increase count)?
  http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&outputformat=application/json&count=10&

Answer (score 0):

You have `outputFormat=text/javascript&` but you need to check what the actual  mime type is for JSON according to the WFS GetCapabilites response of the server, in your case:

> http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cits/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&version=1.1.0&

Probably you'll find it's `application/json`